# Forma mais simples para criar array circular em Java

Tags: java, lista, estrutura-de-dados

Estou procurando uma forma mais enxuta (clean code) para criar um array circular em Java.

Por exemplo, dado a seguinte lista:

```
ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
```

Gostaria de passar como parâmetro o índice e um offset e o método me retorne o valor:

```
String valor = metodo(1,2);
// retorno => C

String valor = metodo(1,-1);
// retorno => C

String valor = metodo(1,5);
// retorno => C
```

Pesquisei e não encontrei nenhuma estrutura de dados do Java que se comporte dessa forma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe lista circular nos tipos nativos da linguagem, então um jeito de resolver é criar um método que recebe a lista, o índice e o *offset*, e retorna o respectivo elemento:

```
public <T> T get(List<T> lista, int index, int offset) {
    index = (index + offset) % lista.size();
    if (index < 0)
        index += lista.size();
    return lista.get(index);
}


List<String> lista = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
// todos retornam "C"
System.out.println(get(lista, 0, 2));
System.out.println(get(lista, 0, -1));
System.out.println(get(lista, 0, 5));
```

Lembrando que os índices começam em zero. Nos seus exemplos você assumiu que o início é 1, mas eu fiz começando em zero (se for o caso, adapte para sua necessidade).

Repare que há um ajuste para o caso de dar negativo. O método também não verifica se o parâmetro `index` está nos limites da lista, nem se a lista é nula ou vazia, etc. Você pode colocar essas verificações se quiser, mas a ideia básica é essa.

---

Uma outra alternativa é criar uma subclasse de `ArrayList` e adicionar o método em questão:

```
public class CircularList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

    public CircularList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        super(c);
    }

    public E getCircular(int index, int offset) {
        index = (index + offset) % this.size();
        if (index < 0)
            index += this.size();
        return this.get(index);
    }
}

CircularList<String> list = new CircularList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
System.out.println(list.getCircular(0, 2));
System.out.println(list.getCircular(0, -1));
System.out.println(list.getCircular(0, 5));
```

Mas não sei se vale a pena criar uma sub-classe só pra isso. Talvez o primeiro método acima já seja suficiente.